# Parsing JSON from a site using wp-posts/posts (JSON REST API wordpress plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

Here's the JSON: http://thecodingdiaries.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category]=Javascript%20Diaries?callback=?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sggakoxx/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://thecodingdiaries.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category]=Javascript%20Diaries&callback=?", 
function (data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        htmlString += 'Title of Post: ' + item.title + '<br />' + 'Content: ' + item.content;
    });
    $('#content').html(htmlString);});
    });
```

I'm using &callback=? at the end of the URL, so it's jsonp.

However, I'm still getting this error in the console:

Refused to execute script from 'http://thecodingdiaries.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category]=Javascript%20Diaries&callback=jQuery21003816753360442817_1416503286274&_=1416503286275' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

In other words, the browser seems to be attaching something after the callback=.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"the browser seems to be attaching something after the callback"* Yes, that's how JSONP works. That's the whole reason why you add the `callback=?` part to the URL in the first place, so that jQuery can add the callback function's name there.

Comment: Hi Juhana -- I did add callback=? to the URL, but I'm still getting that error.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. You misread my comment.

Comment: @Juhana, Oh, I see. Thanks. Any ideas re: why jsonp is not working?